# Does ImageDataGenerator changes (preprocess) all data or only the new ones?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, rescale

I created a mobileNetv2 cnn model and using the imageDataGenerator with the preprocess parameter. Now I am asking myself whether it it enough for resclaling or does imageDataGenerator only modify the new images, which would mean I need to rescale the images still beforehand?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user17288959,If you would have used `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` with preprocess function that will be applied on each input. The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank 3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape. Thanks!